# plot a decision curve for logistic regression with gaussian Kernel

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave

I have tried using logistic regression with polynomial feature, and fortunately its working fine for me and also I am able to plot the decision curve. I have used map_feature function for polynomial features. (I referred Prof Andrew's notes on logistic regression with regularization) : http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex5/ex5.html

Now I am trying to achieve the same using Gaussian Kernel instead of taking polynomial features. Fortunately my cost function (j_theta) works fine and decreases after every iteration and I get my final theta value.
The problem that I face now is HOW DO I PLOT THE DECISION BOUNDARY here

```
I am using Octave to develop the algorithms and plot the graphs..
```

Below is the details to my data set size

Original Data set:

```
Data Set (x):  [20*3] where the first column is the intercept or the bias column

1.00  2.0000   1.0000
1.00  3.0000   1.0000
1.00  4.0000   1.0000
1.00  5.0000   2.0000
1.00  5.0000   3.0000
 .
 .
 .
```

Data set with new features after implementation of Gaussian Kernal

```
Data set (f) : [20*21] the first column is the intercept column with all values as 1

1.0000e+000  1.0000e+000  6.0653e-001  1.3534e-001  6.7379e-003 . . . . . . . . 
1.0000e+000  6.0653e-001  1.0000e+000  6.0653e-001  8.2085e-002 . . . . . . . .
1.0000e+000  1.3534e-001  6.0653e-001  1.0000e+000  3.6788e-001
1.0000e+000  6.7379e-003  8.2085e-002  3.6788e-001  1.0000e+000
.               .
.               . 
.               .
.               .
.               .
```

The cost Function graph that I get after applying gradient descent on my new featured data set (f) is :

[image]

Hence I get my new theta value:

```
theta: [21*1]
 3.8874e+000
 1.1747e-001
 3.5931e-002
-8.5937e-005
-1.2666e-001
-1.0584e-001
 .
 .
 .
```

The problem that I face now is how do I construct my decision curve upon my original dataset having new features data set and theta value. I have no clue how do I proceed.

I would be glad if I get some clue, or tutorials, or link that could help me solve my problem.

Appreciate you help . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The referenced Andrew's [note](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex5/ex5.html) actually contains a very good example of how to draw the decision boundary. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440658/multi-layer-perceptron-finding-the-separating-curve/14449093#14449093) stackoverflow post. The basic steps to follow are as below:

1. Choose a resolution based on the range of your input data, or feature vector `X`.
2. Create a grid made by every points within the resolution.
3. Visit each point in the grid, using your learned logistic regression model, predict the score.
4. Use the score as the `Z` variable (the height on the contour plot), plot the contour curve.

In the sample code below, we assume a 2d feature space each ranges from -1 to 200. We choose a step size of 1.5 and then for each point in the grid, we call the model `predictor` -- `map_feature(u,v) x theta` to get the point score. Finally the plot is drawn by calling `contour` function in matlab.

> Plotting the decision boundary here will be trickier than plotting the
>   best-fit curve in linear regression. You will need to plot the 
>   $\theta^T x = 0$ line implicity, by plotting a contour. This can be
>   done by evaluating $\theta^Tx$ over a grid of points representing the
>   original $u$ and $v$ inputs, and then plotting the line where
>   $\theta^Tx$ evaluates to zero.
>   The plot implementation for Matlab/Octave is given below.

```
% Define the ranges of the grid
u = linspace(-1, 1.5, 200);
v = linspace(-1, 1.5, 200);

% Initialize space for the values to be plotted
z = zeros(length(u), length(v));

% Evaluate z = theta*x over the grid
for i = 1:length(u)
    for j = 1:length(v)
        % Notice the order of j, i here!
        z(j,i) = map_feature(u(i), v(j))*theta;
    end
end

% Because of the way that contour plotting works
% in Matlab, we need to transpose z, or
% else the axis orientation will be flipped!
z = z'
% Plot z = 0 by specifying the range [0, 0]
contour(u,v,z, [0, 0], 'LineWidth', 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Greeness, I saw the post, Actually the plot is suitable for 2D but when I consider Logistic regression or SVM using Gaussian Kernel my  features turns into the number of training set. I.e though my original features are only two, when I use gaussian kernel my new set of features transforms into the number of training set. and hence my theta is learnt from the the new features set which is m(no of training set) dimensional. I was wondering if there is something by which I can convert the data back to 2D feature set and get the decision boundary.